# Show that an embedding from a compact, smooth manifold to a connected smooth manifold is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M,N$ be nonempty, smooth manifold of the same dimension.  Let $N$ be compact and $M$ be connected.  Suppose that $f:N\rightarrow M$ is an embedding.  We want to show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Since $f$ is an embedding, then we know that

1. $f(N)\subset M$ is a smooth submanifold, and
2. $f:N\rightarrow f(N)$ is a diffeomorphism. That is we identify the domain $N$ with its image $f(N)\subset M$ such that $N\subset M$.

We would like to show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.  So, we need to show $f$ is an invertible smooth map.

Comment: In the first paragraph you mean $f : N \rightarrow M$ ?

Comment: Yes, I mean $f:N\rightarrow M$

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Smooth embeddings that are homeomorphisms but not diffeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321250/smooth-embeddings-that-are-homeomorphisms-but-not-diffeomorphisms)

Since we have an embedding, then $f$ is an immersion.

Since $f$ is an immersion and the dimension of $M$ and $N$ are the same, then we have a local diffeomorphism.

Therefore, $f^{-1}:M\rightarrow N$ is also smooth. We have shown $f$ is an invertible smooth map. Hence, $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: You also need to show that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: How would I show that?

Comment: Hint: Connectedness of $M$ is crucial. Do you know the typical argument for showing some subset of a connected space is the whole space?

Comment: No I do not know this.

Comment: @JackLee Sounds familiar. what is it please?is it to do with connected components?

Comment: @JackLee Oh wait I think I know. We can't have $S$ to be proper, open and closed in connected nonempty $C$, so prove $S$ is nonempty open and closed in $C$ to deduce $S=C$?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: Yes, that's the argument I was referring to.

Comment: Thanks Prof @JackLee!