# Why is the inverse of a smooth embedding smooth?

Tags: proof-explanation, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

From Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*:

> *Proposition 5.2* (Images of Embeddings as Submanifolds). Suppose $M$ is a
> smooth manifold with or without boundary, $N$ is a smooth manifold, and
> $F: N \to M$ is a smooth embedding. Let $S = F(N)$. With the subspace
> topology, $S$ is a topological manifold, and it has a unique smooth
> structure making it into an embedded submanifold of $M$ with the
> property that $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.
>
> *Proof*. If we give $S$ the subspace topology that it inherits from $M$,
> then the assumption that $F$ is an embedding means that $F$ can be
> considered as a homeomorphism from $N$ onto $S$, and thus $S$ is a
> topological manifold. We give S a smooth structure by taking the
> smooth charts to be those of the form $(F(U), \phi \circ F^{-1})$, where $(U, \phi)$
> is any smooth chart for $N$; smooth compatibility of these charts
> follows immediately from the smooth compatibility of the
> corresponding charts for $N$. With this smooth structure on $S$, the map
> $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image (essentially by definition)...

Why is $F^{-1}$ smooth?

Answer (score 2):

This holds because smooth embeddings are diffeomorphisms onto their images, so the inverse (suitably restricted to be well-defined) is smooth by definition. See the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321364/458920